# Spring Security: Authenticate REST api only if not already authenticated via form login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

All,

I have a spring boot app with MVC and REST end points. The users of the web application login using form based authentication (first configuration below). There are also REST endpoints exposed that will be invoked by external apps - these are authenticated using JWT (second configuration below).

Once the users login, I would like to invoke the REST end points (/api/**) without authenticating via JWT since the user has already logged in via form based auth. So I would basically like to use JWT authentication only if the user is not authenticated (SecurityContext does not have the auth). I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class UserRole1ConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")))
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/userrole1/**")
                        .hasRole(Role.USERROLE1.name())
                        .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/userrole1/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/userrole1/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/userrole1/dashboard")
                        .and()
                    .logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/userrole1/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/userrole1/login")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll();
        }
    }
```

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class RestConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/register")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/userrole1/**")
                        .hasRole(Role.USERROLE1.name())
                    .antMatchers("/api/userrole2/**")
                        .hasRole(Role.USERROLE2.name())
                    .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtil, jwtConfig))
                    .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(jwtUtil, jwtConfig, userDetailsService, authenticationManager()))
                    .sessionManagement()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                        .and()
                    .csrf()
                        .disable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: REST is stateless, therefore you can't use form login. Form login uses HTTP sessions.

Answer (score -2):

You have this already

.antMatchers("/api/register")
.permitAll()

This will allow unauthenticated requests.
What else are you looking for exactly?

Comment: `/api/register` is just one URL that should be allowed for all. 

`What else are you looking for exactly?` - If the user is authenticated using form based authentication, I would like to invoke `/api/userrole1/**` endpoints WITHOUT authenticating via JWT again.